# How to use Firebase BoM in Kotlin Gradle dsl?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle-kotlin-dsl

How does this look it kotlin DSL:

```
dependencies {
  // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
  implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0')
}
```

The above is the current recommended at [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.2.0"))
}
```

Reference: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:bom_import

Answer (score 0):

```
in
```

> build.gradle.kts

instead of using

```
dependencies {
        implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2')
}
```

> use

```
dependencies {
       implementation (platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2"))
}
```